# Facebook Graph API Video Appears in XX Posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I have a video that has been crossposted to a number of other pages, how do I see a list of pages that have actually crossposted the video?  The information I'm looking for is clearly visible in the Creator Studio by looking at:

[image]

The Edge: {video-id}/crosspost_shared_pages, lists pages that have permission to crosspost the video NOT the pages to have actually gone through the effort and posted the video to their page.

The Edge: {video-id}/sharedposts, doesn't give me what I'm looking for

The Endpoint: {owner_of_video_page_id}_{video_id}?fields=shares, doesn't give me what I'm looking for

What am I missing?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: unfortunately no, I haven't